# `spark-submit` vanilla Python scripts without Spark libraries

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have access to a Spark cluster, and my Spark programs typically start with

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Here's the question: I have a Python program that doesn't yet use any Spark libraries or RDDs, so there is no need for me to create a `SparkSession` like above. Can I `spark-submit` vanilla Python scripts (which doesn't import Spark modules) to run on a single-node?

Comment: you can do that. It will run as normal python job like python command. It will only use single node not whole cluster

Comment: I think to run spark-submit, you need spark session available. I doubt you will be able to run and I don't understand what advantage you get by doing that.

Comment: @PiyushP the benefit is that I can take advantage of the compute resources in the cluster, even if I'm only using one box. Did that answer your question, or did I miss your point?

Comment: @rishai you cannot run cluster mode without sparksession. If you want to use it on client mode, then that is not a good idea unless you dynamically assign the host where the application will be spun up.

Comment: @PiyushP hmm? why would using client-mode not a be a good idea in general? is that what you meant?

Comment: client mode runs the application on that specific host. So, if you run multiple applications from the same node, you will have more load on that specific node instead of distributing the load across the cluster.

Comment: got it @PiyushP. I am now running in cluster-mode, albeit only running in the driver node that spins up (since it's not using Spark libraries for distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have a 'yes' and a 'no' in the comments, so I will add 'it depends' :)

If you `spark-submit` your python code in `client` mode, most likely it'll work since it will simply be executed inside local Spark driver process.

But if you try to use `--deploy-mode=cluster`, its going to fail with exception `"User did not initialize spark context"` or smth like that, because without a code to create `SparkSession` the driver simply won't be instantiated in the allocated container.

Comment: Yes, you're right on - I tried cluster deployment mode and it failed. And client-mode succeeded. The issue, though, with client mode is that people do `spark-submit` on a launcher box in the company. So running on the launcher box, as I recall, is bad practice as it ties up the launcher box for everyone, and my job will suffer as it's using shared resources. So I guess the solution here is to use cluster mode, but create a dummy `SparkSession` which I never use.

Comment: Yes, creating a `SparkSession` will let you run in cluster mode. But then you probably won't be able to run as simple `$ python <script.py>` (don't know how critical it is) unless you add some logic to init `SparkSession` conditionally.

Comment: What do you mean? I was planning to do `spark-submit --deploymode cluster myPythonScript.py`. I did not know you could do use the `python` command for a Spark script...is that what you meant? I'm a bit confused as to why you brought up using the `python` command/interpreter.

Comment: I just thought that IF you decide to run it as simple python (before putting any meaningful Spark code into it) you won't be able to do it. Sorry for confusion :)

Comment: @mazaneicha I'm researching Spark and I'm also confused by this (although many things might have changed in Spark since this answer was given:P). If I initiate a new `SparkSession` and run my python script in cluster mode, will my script simply execute in one of the worker nodes without any distribution that `DataFrame`s provide? Have I understood this correctly? Thanks!